# Projecting a texture in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, graphics

FIXED by setting near clipping plane to 1, rather than 0 (not sure why it was like that to start with). See the question for skeleton code, and Adrian's answer for how and why this works.

I have a few different camera positions, and my scene consists of a single quad.

The quad is such that it projects exactly onto the viewport/window in the first frame. I want to project a texture from this camera position onto the quad. The texture also covers the viewport exactly.

The first thing I did was

```
    // GL_QUADS...
    glTexCoord2f( /*one corner of s,t space*/);
    glVertex3f(/* appropriate vertex */);;
```

and ended up with something like (picture not mine) [image]

And then I realised yes, of course, it needs to be a *projective* transformation. According to [these notes](http://www.opengl.org/resources/code/samples/sig99/advanced99/notes/node80.html):

1. A modelview transform to orient the projection in the scene.
2. A projective transform (perspective or orthogonal).
3. A scale and bias to map the near clipping plane to texture coordinates.

Now that it works, here's a rough implementation of the code:

```
// in init code
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);

double ratio = width/height;

// set up FROM modelview matrix
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();


gluPerspective(pcam._fov/ratio, ratio, 1, far_z);
gluLookAt(/* FROM camera's parameters */);

glTexGeni(GL_Q, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR); //S, T, R and Q
GLfloat Splane[] = {1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f}; //S, T, R and Q, diagonal
glTexGenfv(GL_S,GL_EYE_PLANE,Splane); //S, T, R and Q

// -- load and bind texture --

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S); //S, T, R and Q

// scale and bias
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.5,0.5,0.0);
glScalef(0.5,0.5,1);

gluPerspective(cam._fov/ratio, ratio, 1, far_z);
gluLookAt(/* TO camera's parameters */);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(/* for each vertex */);
glEnd();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S); //S, T, R and Q
```

Comment: I think you may have your TO and FROM cameras mixed up. Is FROM/pcam the projector?  GL_TEXTURE should contain the transforms for the projector rather than the view camera. I don't know if that would solve your problem, though.

Comment: Yes it is the projector. I'm sure I am supplying the details correctly. Even if I change the perspective/lookat calls to both use the same camera details it looks wrong...

Comment: Do both cameras share the *exact* same parameters -- orientation, position and view frustum -- at the time the problem crops up? Why are you setting the *view* according to the projector and the texture coordinates according to the view camera? Otherwise your transforms and eye space coefficients look the same as in the notes you've cited, so at this point I'm stumped as to what might be going on.

Comment: Yes, to *test* this I am attempting to project back into exactly the same camera. Once this works, I can try other cameras. I am also stumped :(

Comment: According to the comments, GL_EYE_LINEAR is enabled for all of S, T, R and Q, right? Are you also setting the R plane to (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0) and the Q plane to (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)? Also I still don't understand why you're setting the view using the projector ("pcam") object, but since you say it's exactly the same as "cam" then it doesn't really matter at this point.

Comment: I've just found it! The near clipping plane needs to be set to 1. Then it works (albeit upside-down, but scaling (0.5,-0.5,1); instead works). Otherwise your advice is spot on. I'll accept your answer and make a note on the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for [glTexGen](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTexGen.xml) (in your case, you want to use `GL_EYE_LINEAR` along with an appropriate set of coefficients as described below) and [glEnable](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glEnable.xml)(`GL_TEXTURE_GEN_*`). When you enable the texgen feature for particular texture coordinate components (S, T, R and/or Q), the values you specify for those components (via `glTexCoord`) are ignored and texture coordinates are instead generated according to the specified `glTexGen` mode.

When computing texture coordinates via `GL_EYE_LINEAR`, vertex coordinates are first transformed into eye space by the current `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix. Once in eye space, for each enabled component (S, T, R, Q), the vertex coordinates are transformed by the inverse of the `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix as defined at the time of the call to `glTexGen`, and the dot product between the resulting coordinates and the coefficients sent to `glTexGen` is then obtained. For each enabled component, the resulting scalar values become the corresponding components (S, T, R and/or Q) of the texture coordinates, which are finally transformed by the `GL_TEXTURE` matrix to produce the final texture coordinates.

For each texture component, the coefficients (a, b, c, d) sent to `glTexGen` define a plane ax + by + cz + d = 0. Assuming (a, b, c) is a vector of unit length, the result of the dot product operation described above represents the distance between this plane and the vertex being processed. If `GL_EYE_LINEAR` is enabled for all four texture components and the plane equations for S, T, R and Q are defined respectively as (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0), and (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), the texture coordinates produced for each texture component are then exactly the same as the original object-space vertex coordinates. Thus, the `GL_TEXTURE` matrix should contain whatever operations are needed to transform these coordinates from object space to texture space: *modeling*, *viewing* and *projection* transforms to convert from object coordinates to normalized device coordinates, plus *scale* and *bias* transforms to convert from normalized device coordinates to texture space.

Comment: Thanks very much for all this, I am now trying to implement it.

Comment: I'm not having much luck. My quad is textured with a single color - it looks like it might be extremely zoomed-in, so we're just seeing one pixel. I'll expand the question

Comment: I notice in your code that you haven't specified the coefficients (via glTexGen) for any of the texture coordinate components. I also notice you haven't set the GL_TEXTURE matrix. You should set the glTexGen coefficients to something like (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0) for S, (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0) for T, etc. This will project your eye space coordinates directly into object space, and you can then apply your view and projection transforms to the GL_TEXTURE matrix to transform from object space into texture space.

Comment: Also, for your particular purposes you want the GL_MODELVIEW matrix to remain the same before and after the call to glTexGen where you set the coefficients. To get the proper texture coordinates, apply your modelview and projection transforms to GL_TEXTURE like you did with GL_MODELVIEW/GL_PROJECTION and don't forget to scale and transform the s and t components by 0.5 as the final step so that the final texture coordinates lie inside the (0,1) range.

Comment: Thank again. Yes, looks much more reasonable now, but the texture is tiled about 4 times (ie comes out too small), and the aspect ratio seems off. I will update details again, maybe there's one last things I've missed?

Comment: I've edited my answer to fix various errors in my explanation and to provide a better answer to your original question.